# django formsets - render fields from a model and save inputs to another model

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have a doubt about using formset with class-based views, that may be simpler, but i couldn't figured out so far.

I have the following models:

```
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
 charcode = models.Charfield(unique=True)

class QuestionModel(models.Model):
 title = models.Charfield()
 type = models.CharField(choices=('text','rate'))

class SurveyModel(models.Model):
 project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectModel)
 active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 questions = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionModel)

class AnswerModel(models.Model):
 question = models.ForeignKey(QuestionModel)
 response_text = models.TextField()
 response_rate = models.IntegerField(choices=(1,2,3,4,5))

class SubmissionModel(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
 survey = models.ForeignKey(SurveyModel)
 answers = models.ManyToManyField(AnswerModel)
```

I need a view to render `questions` of a active `survey` so a user can fill it in a form that will create `answers` objects and a `submission` object.

so, I have this url:
`path('submission/<str:charcode>/, SubmissionView.as_view())`

this view that receives `charcode` from url:

```
class SubmissionView(CreateView):
 form_class = SubmissionFormSet
 template_name='create_submission.html'
```

and this formset (in construction):

```
class SubmissionFormSet(form.BaseFormSet):
 # need to get questions from survey_objects.get(project__charcode = 'charcode', active=True)
 # define each field based on question type to properly widget choice
 # save answers and submission based on responses from user
```

i really have no idea yet, but i guess i must use formset_factory, maybe inside view like `AnswerFormset =  formset_factory(AnswerForm, formset=SubmissionFormSet)` but not sure how to